# Git after wiping hard drive

Tags: git, pull, corrupt

I have a project hosted with git. I just recently had to reinstall ubuntu, and am in the process of getting everything set up again. I was able to log back into git and get all of my files back, but now am having some trouble.

When I try to pull, using the same syntax as I would normally, I get this:

```
$ git pull Peter master
fatal: 'Peter' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My git config looks like this:

```
$ git config --list
user.name=Peter
user.email=****@***.com
branch.master.remote=Peter
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Git branch looks like this:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/Peter/HEAD -> Peter/master
  remotes/Peter/master
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'd be happy to provide whatever other information is necessary. Thank you

Comment: Probably missing your remote definition.  What's the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: Thank you! git remote -v outputs nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a remote defined in your config, something like this :

```
[remote "Peter"]
    url = ssh:/xxxx/git/ccc.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/peter/*
```

Use `git remote add Peter xxxx` to add it

Comment: Thank you! How do i find out what xxxx is?

Comment: That's the adress of your distant repository, for example `ssh://yourname@yourcomputer.yourdomain.com/home/yournameagain/git/yourproject.git` if you use ssh (and in this case it's a bare repository hence the .git)